# Daily Challenges Post Times

Tags: xbox-360, halo-reach, achievements

I am in the EST time zone and completed a challenge after midnight and wondering **when are challenges posted**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be 6AM in the EST.

http://www.bungie.net/stats/reach/globalchallenges.aspx

Here you can see how much time is left before new challenges are available.

As for the weekly challenges, those end on Monday at 6AM. (EST)